# JPA buddy error when generating JPA Entities from DB

Tags: spring-boot, jpa-buddy

i'm currently using JPA buddy in my spring boot application to generate JPA Entities from my sakila database. But when i use this feature JPA buddy alway listed all of database tables and views including system tables and views (here is what on my JPA buddy  reverse engineering show https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmAQq.png)
How can i make JPA buddy only list data tables and not system tables.

I expect JPA buddy to only list data tables and not system tables